# getting [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to implement a client/server program in python. My client side script gets an error when server has nothing to send(server temporarily has nothing to say).

this is part of my client code:

```
def __init__(self, view, n):
    self.view = view
    self.n = n
    self.s = socket.socket()
    self.s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8020))
    try:
        self.__game_request()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.printmsg)
        t1.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print("some error happened")
        print(e)

def printmsg(self):
    while True:
        
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            msg = self.s.recv(128) #      Error occurs here
            if msg:
                print(msg.decode())
                self.s.send("You told sth".encode())
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error")
            print(e)
            self.s = socket.socket()
            self.s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8020))
            self.s.send('{"type" : "oo"}'.encode())
```

and this is part my server code :

```
 def __init__(self,n,player1 , player2):
     self.p1 = player1
     self.p2 = player2
     player1.send_message(("id" + str(id(self))))
     player2.send_message(("id" + str(id(self))))

     time.sleep(3)
     player1.send_message("You R Player 1")
     time.sleep(4)
     player1.send_message("another")
     
     # in this part, server has no message yet
```

I will get `[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer in python` in the client side. server still works.
I think for some reason the connection does not keeps alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a reference to the client socket in server-side code. Since I don't do anything with the client socket after the last message that has been sent, python will lose the reference to client socked (client socket is encapsulated in player object in above code) and clears it from memory and implicitly closes the connection.

So for avoiding this error, I kept the references to player objects.

Answer (score 0):

Sadeye. Add line " farid = chook " to the server side code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where should the line be added? How and why will it work? What is Sadeye?